# laravel-5.7: data is not saving into database, Object not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to save data into db but its not saving and says that object not found, can anyone suggest me solution, i am following this tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/10

controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::all();

    return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
}

public function create()
{
    return view('projects.create');
}

public function store()
{
    $project = new Project();
    $project->title = request('title');
    $project->description = request('description');
    $project->save();

    return redirect('/projects');
}
```

routes:

```php
Route::get('/projects','ProjectsController@index');
Route::post('/projects','ProjectsController@store');
Route::get('/projects/create','ProjectsController@create');
```

create.blade.php:

```php
<form method="POST" action="/projects">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Project title">
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea name="description" placeholder="Project description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Create Project</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

index.blade.php:

```php
@foreach($projects as $project)
    <li>{{ $project->title }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The code seems to be right... can you post the message error that you're receiving?

Comment: Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.7

Comment: It would help if you update the post with that error message, and include information like the url from your address bar and the url of the create page. It sounds like you might be redirecting to a url that doesn't match what you have configured for the website in Apache.

Comment: this is url of error page  http://localhost/projects    and this is url or create page    http://localhost/laravel/project/public/projects/create

Comment: Can you edit your post and include those details in the question? All of the code you posted is correct - those errors are what show the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laravel code you've posted is correct under a properly configured website. The error from your comments:

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The
>   link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please
>   inform the author of that page about the error. If you think this is a
>   server error, please contact the webmaster. Error 404 localhost
>   Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.7

is an ***Apache error page***, which means it's not requesting a page from your laravel project at all. The data is probably saving in your database, but then you redirect away to a page that is outside your project, and Apache can't find it.

Your website is located at `http://localhost/laravel/public`, which means you need to access the projects page at `http://localhost/laravel/public/projects`. However,  `redirect('/projects')` gives you an *absolute* path instead of a *relative* path, sending you to `http://localhost/projects`, which does not exist.

### Solutions

Since this is a local development project, I'm going to skip the issues with the improper Apache configuration and focus on other ways to avoid the error.

#### Option 1

Use a [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('/projects','ProjectsController@index')->name('projects.index');
```

and use the name of the route for the redirect:

```
return redirect()->route('projects.index');
```

This *should* generate correct urls within your project.

#### Option 2

Use `serve` for development instead of Apache.

Open a terminal in your Laravel project directory and run this command:

```
php artisan serve
```

This will start PHP's built-in webserver at http://localhost:8000, skipping Apache entirely. During development this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed out passing request parameter in the controller store()

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $project = new Project();
    $project->title = $request->title;
    $project->description = $request->description;
    $project->save();
    return redirect('/projects');
}
```

And also don't forget to include `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` above(outside) controller class.

Comment: This isn't required when using `request('title')`, because the `request()` function retrieves the Request from the container directly (instead of using dependency injection on the controller method)

Comment: @programmer0001 - have you included Project class in controller?

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Project;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
     $projects = Project::all();

     return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
     return view('projects.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
     $project = new Project();

     $project->title = $request('title');
     $project->description = $request('description');

     $project->save();

     return redirect('/projects.index')   }
}

Comment: I would suggest try first debugging the code. For example inside store method at first line  put die('test') to see if the request is coming to that store() or not.

Comment: Also you can try one more. Modified - use App\Project as Project;