# XAMPP Object not found

Tags: php, windows, laravel, xampp

I'm working on a Laravel project but when I tried to access the login I get the following error.

[image]

Is a new installation I haven't made any changes yet but to run the following command "php artisan make:auth" so I'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: Can you please check does auth folder created in both controllers and resources ? 404 only means in resources auth views isn't created

Comment: This is an Apache error page, which means your site isn't set up correctly in xampp. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55091642/6038111) might be related

Comment: Check if mod_rewrite module is enabled

Comment: check your xampp server is properly working or not.

Comment: Please paste your url here. We might get something from url. Because I was facing this kind of problem and then found issue was with url.